# how to use regular expression in python to get memory details in product name

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use regular expression to parse memory of the product.
product name : 1) Lg K42 Blu Tim Smartphone **64 gb**
2) Xiaomi Smartphone 0.128 gb ram 4 gb. tim quadband - Redmi Note 9 **128gb** Grigio Tim.

How to get the 64 gb using regex in python. gb may be small or caps and memory value may be contains 2 or 3 numbers

```
import xlwt
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import re
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import date

class cometmobiles:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url='https://www.comet.it/smartphone-e-telefonia/smartphone-e-cellulari/smartphone'
        self.country='IT'
        self.currency='euro'
        self.VAT='Included'
    def comet(self):
        #try:
            wb = xlwt.Workbook()
            ws = wb.add_sheet('Sheet1',cell_overwrite_ok=True)
            ws.write(0,0,"Product_Url")
            ws.write(0,1,"Product_Manufacturer")
            ws.write(0,2,"Product_Model")
            ws.write(0,3,"Product_memory")
            ws.write(0,4,"Product_Price")
            ws.write(0,5,"Currency")
            ws.write(0,6,"VAT")
            ws.write(0,7,"Shipping")
            ws.write(0,8,"Country")
            ws.write(0,9,"Date")
            wb.save(r"C:\Users\Karthick R\Desktop\VS code\comet.xls")
            driver=webdriver.Chrome()      
            today = date.today()
            driver.maximize_window()
            driver.implicitly_wait(30)
            driver.get(self.url)
            wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
            cookies = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//i[@class="btn-close-popup fas fa-times"]')
            cookies.click()
            time.sleep(5)
            print("clicked")
            x = 0
            titles = []
            models = []
            memorys = []
            prices = []
            links =[]
            product_links = []
            while True:
                containers = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4"]')                
                i = 1
                for container in containers:
                    url = container.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class="sotto-cat__products__item"]')
                    urls = url.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
                    i = i + 1
                    product_links.append(urls)
                print(product_links)
                x+=1
                time.sleep(5)
                driver.get(self.url+"?p="+str(x))                    
                print("next page") 
                if driver.current_url == self.url:
                    break
            for links in product_links:
                driver.get(links)
                time.sleep(10)
                #product links
                print(driver.current_url)
                source = driver.page_source
                soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'html.parser')
                #title
                title = soup.find('h1',{'class':'scheda-prodotto__info__col-sx__title'}).text
                y = re.search('([^\s]+)',title)
                print(title) 
                titles.append(y.group(1))
                #models
                model = re.sub(y.group(1),"",title).strip()
                print(model)
                models.append(model) 
                #memory
                memory = re.search('^[0-9]{2,3}+[A-Za-z]',model).strip()
                print(memory)
                memorys.append(memory)
                #price             
                price = soup.find('span',{'class':'caption__price'}).text 
                print(price)
            i=0
            while i<len(titles):
                ws.write(i+1,0,str(links[i]))
                ws.write(i+1,1,str(titles[i]))
                ws.write(i+1,2,str(models[i]))
                ws.write(i+1,3,str(memorys[i]))
                ws.write(i+1,4,str(prices[i]))
                ws.write(i+1,5,str(self.currency))
                ws.write(i+1,6,str(self.VAT))
                ws.write(i+1,7,str(self.shipping))
                ws.write(i+1,8,str(self.country))
                ws.write(i+1,9,str(date.today()))
                i=i+1
                wb.save(r"C:\Users\Karthick R\Desktop\VS code\comet.xls")
        #except:
            #pass
comets=cometmobiles()
comets.comet()
```

Comment: What's that ```0.128 gb``` ? You want the regex to match this as well ?

Comment: 0.128 gb should not be print match only 128gb

Comment: nope i want only 128gb

Comment: Please check my solution

Answer (score 1):

```
input_str = "Lg K42 Blu Tim Smartphone 64 gb "

import re
output_value =  re.search('[0-9]*.(?=gb)',input_str)
print (output_value[0])
```

Output : 64

input_str = "Redmi Note 9 128gb Grigio Tim"
Output : 128

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out.

```
import re
s = 'Lg K42 Blu Tim Smartphone 64 gb Xiaomi Smartphone 0.128 gb ram 4 gb. tim quadband - Redmi Note 9 128Gb Grigio Tim.'

f = re.findall(r'\b\d{2,3}\s*gb\b',s,re.I)
print(f)
```

```
['64 gb', '128 gb', '128Gb']
```